# How to conditionally change values of a Google Sheet using another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to modify an existing Google Sheet using a Form response sheet. Suppose in the sheet I need modified I have column G called "Annotated Asset ID" which contains a list of asset IDs. Now in the form response sheet there are two columns; Old ID (D) and New ID (E). I would like to check Column G of the existing sheet to see if it contains the Old ID and if it does I need to replace it with the New ID.

What is a good way to do this?

Form Response:
[image: Form Response]

Existing Sheet:
[image: Existing Sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with Apps Script.*

#### Steps:

- Extract out the old and new IDs from the form response sheet
- For each of the old IDs, use a [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) to search your column for the old ID in the existing sheet:

  - `const cell = sheet.getRange("G1:G").createTextFinder("old-id").findNext()`
- Replace the ID if cell isn't null:

  - `if (cell) { cell.setValue("new-id") }`

#### Code Example:

```js
function replaceIds() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const formResponseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("response-sheet-name")
  const existingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("existing-sheet-name")

  const oldIds = formResponseSheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues().flat()
  const newIds = formResponseSheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues().flat()

  const rangeToCheck = existingSheet.getRange("G1:G")

  oldIds.forEach(function(id, index) {
    let cell = rangeToCheck.createTextFinder(id).findNext()
    
    if (cell) {
      cell.setValue(newIds[index])
    }
  })
}
```

- Add this to your project from the `Tools > Script editor` menu item. Make sure to change the response sheet nad existing sheet names.
- Save the script and run the function. You will need to authorise it to run on your behalf.

Comment: I am getting an error on these two lines: "  oldIds.forEach(function(id, index) {
    let cell = rangeToCheck.createTextFinder(id).findNext() " ; it is saying "Exception: Argument cannot be null: findText"

Comment: Log and check the value of id. Looks like it's empty.

Comment: some of the ids are empty is there an effective way to bypass them? such as: "if (id != null){ ....}